# Does anyone can fix my learning C# code of randomNumn and writeOut?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem of my C# code. Here is an code that I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Console_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(writeOut(5,4));
          Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int randomNum()
        {
            return 4;
        }

        static int writeOut(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int total = num1 + num2;
          Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a one error, can anyone fix my code? I'm not good with C#.
Error says not all code paths returns a value.

Comment: `writeOut` doesn't return a value, so either return one or change the return type to `void`. If you decide not to return a value you'll want to change `Console.WriteLine(writeOut(5,4));` as well.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 static int writeOut(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int total = num1 + num2;
          Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
```

This function is wrong.
After the Static it says "int" this means your function must return an int.
at the end of the function I think you want to add "Return total;"
this will fix your error.

```
 static int writeOut(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int total = num1 + num2;
          Console.WriteLine(total);
          return total;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Console_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(writeOut(5,4));
          Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int randomNum()
        {
            return 4;
        }

        static int writeOut(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
          
        }
    }
}
```